# Thymeleaf template passing objects through forms and get/post mapping

Tags: java, spring, forms, oop, thymeleaf

I have the following thymeleaf template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:replace="fragments::head(title='Film zoeken')">
        <title>Film zoeken</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav th:replace="fragments::menu"></nav>
        <form method="get" th:object="${zoekForm}" th:action="@{/film/zoeken}">
            <label>
                Nummer:
            </label>
            <span th:errors="*{id}"></span>
            <input th:field="*{id}" type="number" autofocus required min="1">
            <button>Zoeken</button>
        </form>

        <th:block th:if="${film}" th:object="${film}">
            <dl>
                <dt>Titel</dt>
                <dd th:text="*{title}"></dd>
                <dt>Regisseur</dt>
                <dd th:text="*{regisseur}"></dd>
                <dt>Uitgekomen op</dt>
                <dd th:text="*{releaseDate}"></dd>
                <dt>Karakters</dt>
                <dd th:each="karakter : *{karakters}" th:text="${karakter}"></dd>
            </dl>

            <form th:if="not ${score}" th:object="${scoreForm}" method="post"
                  th:action="@{/film/{id}/score(id=${param.id})}">
                <label>
                    Score:
                    <span th:errors="*{score}"></span>
                    <input th:field="*{score}" type="number" required min="1" max="10">
                </label>
                <button>Bewaren</button>
            </form>

            <div th:if="${score}">
                Je score voor deze film is <strong th:text="${score.score}"></strong>
            </div>

        </th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have two `@GetMapping` methods and then the final `@PostMapping`.
The first one do a `modelAndView.addObject(new ZoekForm(null));`, so it shows only the first form.
Then, the second getmapping do a thing with the content (it shows the film data) and then it has a
`modelAndView.addObject("scoreForm", new ScoreForm(null));`.

So far the template shows 1) search form for a movie, 2) the film data and finally a field to give the movie a score.

I need to give a score (hit the button from the second form) and show the div

```
            <div th:if="${score}">
                Je score voor deze film is <strong th:text="${score.score}"></strong>
            </div>
```

but the website must keep showing the film data. Now, when I hit that score button, all goes away.
It seems like the `th:if=${film}` is not happening. Clues?

(I assume also that the score object needs to be passed in the post, because if I look up again the same movie, I must be unable to give it a score).

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf doesn't create objects for you. You need to pass it the object in your controller. You can either do it in every controller method that returns this template page or just use `@ModelAttribute` (place it as a method to your controller)

```
@ModelAttribute("film")
public Film methodNameDoesntMatter() {
    return new Film();
}
```

This will occur on every page reload, so Film object is always new. Make sure there are getters/setters and no arg constructor defined - this is important for thymleaf

Comment: Alright. Got it. But after the last `@PostMapping` I need to keep all the movie information on screen. If I do every time `new Form(...)` or `new Object(...)`, I am keeping nothing.
Edit: with `no arg constructor defined` you mean simple constructors?

Comment: with no arg constructor, i mean constructor with no arguments, e.g. default constructor

Comment: Keeping the form filled on reload is a different question, doesn't make much sense to me to be honest, since a form for submission is not supposed to stay filled, but totally doable by creating a kind of a cache in the controller or whatever and grabbing the Film object from there. So create a component, call it userCache, make it session scoped and have it keep an object of Film as attribute. In the @ModelAttribute always return that Film from that component and that is it.

Comment: Mmm. I don't get you.
I received this clue: 
`<form th:if="not ${score}" th:object="${scoreForm}" method="post"
      th:action="@{/film/{id}/score(id=${param.id})}">`

I asume the first {id} is the filmId, en de id within the score is the actual score the user gives to the film. I don't now how to handle this in my controller.

So far so god i have this in the controller:
`@PostMapping("{id}/score")
    public ModelAndView scoreBewaren(@PathVariable long id, @Valid Score score, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirect, Principal principal) { ...`